# Identifying a .pdf that shares a file name with .txt and then moving them both -ksh

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm working a script whose purpose is to sort through the .pdfs in a directory and verify that there exists a matching .txt ie:

```
test.txt
test.pdf
```

and then if the .txt exists move them both to another folder. I can't figure out how to do the matching though. Here is what I'm trying:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for PDF in /top/input/*.pdf
do
if [ -e "$PDF".txt ];then
   mv ./$PDF.* ./paired/
fi
done
```

it works if I'm using test data instead of variable  names, but I can't figure out how to actually make it dynamically find the file name and search for it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for PDF in /top/input/*.pdf
do
   TXT=${PDF%.pdf}.txt
   if [ -e "$TXT" ];then
      echo mv "$PDF" "$TXT" ./paired/
   fi
done
```

Remove `echo` from `mv` after testing if it's already correct.

Note:

```
   if [ -e "$TXT" ];then
      echo mv "$PDF" "$TXT" ./paired/
   fi
```

Could be simply

```
   [ -e "$TXT" ] && echo mv "$PDF" "$TXT" ./paired/
```

Comment: I attempted to do this previously, and just tested again but it isn't finding the matching .txt

Comment: @user2062818 Are the `.txt` files existing in `/top/input` as well? You can see how they are produced by doing `echo "$PDF = $TXT"` after `TXT=${PDF%.pdf}.txt` (next line).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the variable $PDF will evaluate to the full path of the pdf file, including the .pdf extension.  So if the filename is /top/input/test.pdf then "$PDF".txt will become /top/input/test.pdf.txt.  Of course, this is not what you want.  So before using $PDF I believe you have strip off the .pdf extension first, then you can tack on the .txt.  Not sure how to strip off the extension in ksh but I believe a simple google will do.

Comment: thats what I assumed and I did try it the way my 'simple google' told me do which is very similar to @konsolebox is doing, but it still isn't working